# Split by comma where not between ( and )

Tags: php, regex

i've problem by using the preg_split method. I wanna split by comma but only if the comma isn't between **(** and **)**.

For example:

```
id,user(id,firstname),image(id)
```

Should return:

```
0 => id
1 => user(id,firstname)
2 => image(id)
```

Comment: you should have enclosures, what's the source of the data? bad CSV form at a guess

Comment: You should do `_match`ing, not splitting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explode complex string by commas in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062241/explode-complex-string-by-commas-in-php) (Just picked the first google link, there are others ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue using `preg_split` with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE`.

```
$tokens = preg_split('#(\,|\(|\))#', 'id,user(id,firstname),image(id)', PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Returns:

```
["id", ",", "user", "(", "id", "firstname", ")", "image", "(", "id", ")"]
```

After that you can parse that array with a simple switch case.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and readable solution might be this:

```
<?php
function parse($str) {
    $str = preg_replace('~(\(.*?),(.*?\))~', '$1_#_PLACEHOLDER_#_$2', $str);

    $items = array();
    foreach (explode(',', $str) as $item) {
        $items[] = str_replace('_#_PLACEHOLDER_#_', ',', $item);
    };
    return $items;
}

var_dump(parse('id,user(id,firstname),image(id)'));
```

It could definitely be done with a single regex, but readability would be severely hurt.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a parser-generator rather than a regex. I'm not familiar with the alternatives in PHP, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3720377/5950) indicates a couple alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to find a parser instead, but it can be done using regular expressions.

Use the following regular expression: `/\G(?> *)(?|([^,]*\((?>\\.|[^()])+\)[^,]*)|(?![()])([^,]+?)) *(?:,|$)/g`

More details here: http://regex101.com/r/nA7dW5

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

The regex `/(\([^()]+\))|([^,]+)/` will match everything, except the commas outside parentheses. Does it helps?

Comment: No, you can't, given that that is for javascript.  Not php; it's a different flavor of regex, not everything is the same.  Use http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php instead.

Comment: And as it stands, the above regex doesn't meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: You can use www.regex101.com to test your regular expression. It uses PHP. Full version details in the "about" tab. Also, my answer should work for OP.